# Edit header with NSURLProtocol?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, mobile-safari

How can I make a webpage opened with a `file://` url protocol send a header of `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"`

I guess it is possible to do through NSURLProtocol but I do not know how.

This is to fix an error I'm receiving when pages that use a `file://` url `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`

Comment: Have you read this document: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html ?

Comment: @nhahtdh It's not related to jquery/ajax, it's socket.io, you need to send this header.

Comment: Can you provide all the information about the libraries you use in the app, and how the server is set up?

Comment: @nhahtdh Server running node/socket.io connecting from a file:// url makes socket.io throw `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` that's the gist of it. You can reproduce the issue by connecting from any file:// because that header is never set. Phonegap can work around this by setting that header.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11728/discussion-between-nhahtdh-and-fancy)